# How can I install PHP 5.6.14 on Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan)?

Tags: macos, installation, php, osx-el-capitan

I recently upgraded from OS X Yosemite to El Capitan, and I needed to re-install PHP. So, I downloaded php (version 5.6.14), ran the `./configure` file, and then ran `sudo make`. However, when doing so, the compilation fails with the following trailing messages:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1
```

I never ran into this message while on Mac OS X 10.9.5 (Yosemite).

How would I resolve this message? I have tried disabling System Integrity Protection (SIP) to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

According to this this GitHub issue report connected to building PHP 5.6.11 beta on Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan), the key problem connected to `libxml2`. Their recommendation in the case of Homebrew is to run this `brew link` command:

```
brew link libxml2 --force
```

But if you are compiling from pure source code, not 100% sure how that would be handled.

That said, I found a similar issue discussed in this [Nokogiri Gist](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/wiki/What-to-do-if-libxml2-is-being-a-jerk)—hilariously titled “What to do if libxml2 is being a jerk”—and the clues point to explicitly pointing to the LibXML2 stuff like this:

```
--with-xml2-include=/usr/local/include/libxml2
```

But—of course—that would be for Nokogiri’s config options. But looking at [the official PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/libxml.installation.php) explains the following:

> The optional **--with-libxml-dir** directive is used to specify the
>   location of *libxml* on the system that PHP is being compiled on,
>   otherwise only the default locations are scanned.

So knowing that it seems adding `--with-libxml-dir` to your `./configure` command—something with a path set as below—should work:

```
--with-libxml-dir=/usr/local/include/libxml2
```

That said, [this person’s website has a nice tutorial](http://www.michaelbagnall.com/blogs/php-gd-fixing-your-php-server-mac-os-x-without-homebrewmacports) on how to compile PHP 5.5.24 in Mac OS X that has been updated to cope with Mac OS X 10.10.5 and as well as Mac OS X 10.11. And if you look through the `./configure` command you can see that person is using `--with-libxml-dir=/usr`. While the info is presented as being for PHP 5.5.24, I imagine he process for PHP 5.6.14 should be similar if not the same. Here is their full `./configure` command for reference:

```
./configure '--prefix=/usr' \
  '--mandir=/usr/share/man' \
  '--infodir=/usr/share/info' \
  '--sysconfdir=/private/etc' \
  '--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs' \
  '--enable-cli' \
  '--with-config-file-path=/etc' \
  '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/Library/Server/Web/Config/php' \
  '--with-libxml-dir=/usr' \
  '--with-openssl=/usr' \
  '--with-kerberos=/usr' \
  '--with-zlib=/usr' \
  '--enable-bcmath' \
  '--with-bz2=/usr' \
  '--enable-calendar' \
  '--disable-cgi' \
  '--with-curl=/usr' \
  '--enable-dba' \
  '--with-ndbm=/usr' \
  '--enable-exif' \
  '--enable-fpm' \
  '--enable-ftp' \
  '--with-icu-dir=/usr' \
  '--with-ldap=/usr' \
  '--with-ldap-sasl=/usr' \
  '--with-libedit=/usr' \
  '--enable-mbstring' \
  '--enable-mbregex' \
  '--with-mysql=mysqlnd' \
  '--with-mysqli=mysqlnd' \
  '--without-pear' \
  '--with-pear=no' \
  '--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd' \
  '--with-mysql-sock=/var/mysql/mysql.sock' \
  '--with-readline=/usr' \
  '--enable-shmop' \
  '--with-snmp=/usr' \
  '--enable-soap' \
  '--enable-sockets' \
  '--enable-sysvmsg' \
  '--enable-sysvsem' \
  '--enable-sysvshm' \
  '--with-tidy' \
  '--enable-wddx' \
  '--with-xmlrpc' \
  '--with-iconv-dir=/usr' \
  '--with-xsl=/usr' \
  '--enable-zip'
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you specifically need a newer version, PHP 5.5.27 comes stock with OS X El Capitan.

You can uncomment (remove #) before the line `LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so` inside of httpd.conf (use `sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf` to access).

Comment: Yes, I would like to install a specific version and enable certain plugins (such as curl). So I do need to install from command line.